# C .so library Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes, shared-objects

Now my code works with a normal c library, but I need to use a .so library from Caen and I get Segmentation fault. This is the code:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL('./libcaenhvwrapper.so.5.56')
lib.CAENHVInitSystem.restype = c_int
lib.CAENHVInitSystem.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, c_char_p, c_char_p, c_char_p]
lib.CAENHVGetError.restype = c_int    

CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t = c_int
sy1527 = CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t(0)
sy2527 = CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t(1)
sy4527 = CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t(2)
sy5527 = CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t(3)
n568 = CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t(4)
v65xx = CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t(5)
n1470 = CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t(6)
v8100 = CAENHV_SYSTEM_TYPE_t(7)

link = c_int
LINKTYPE_TCPIP = link(0)
LINKTYPE_RS232 = link(1)
LINKTYPE_CAENET = link(2)
LINKTYPE_USB = link(3)
LINKTYPE_OPTLINK = link(4)
LINKTYPE_USB_VCP = link(5)

string15=c_char*15
address=string15('1','3','7','.','1','3','8','.','1','3','.','2','0','3','\0')

userName = c_char_p('user')
passwd = c_char_p('user')
ret_init =  lib.CAENHVInitSystem(0, 0, address, userName, passwd)
```

when I try to call the function I get a segmentation fault. I think the types are correctly defined. Below you can see a piece of code which works ok.

```
from ctypes import *
lib2 = CDLL('/lib64/libc.so.6')
string15=c_char*15
address=string15('1','3','7','.','1','3','8','.','1','3','.','2','0','3','\0')
address1=create_string_buffer('137.138.13.203')
address2=c_char_p('137.138.13.200')

userName = c_char_p('user')
passwd = c_char_p('user')

a= lib2.strncmp(address, userName, c_int(4))    
a= lib2.strncmp(userName, address, 4)
a= lib2.strncmp(address2, address, 15)

lib2.printf('%d\n', ret_init)
lib2.printf('%s\n', address)
lib2.printf('%s\n', address1)
lib2.printf('%s\n', address2)
lib2.printf('%d\n', lib2.strlen(address))
lib2.printf('%d\n', lib2.strlen(address1))
lib2.printf('%d\n', lib2.strlen(adrress2))
```

Comment: Looking at the available docs online, does it make a difference with you put a C string as the first argument?

Comment: You should edit your question to show the signature of `CAENHVInitSystem` as provided in the corresponding `.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick search:

```
CAENHVRESULT CAENHVInitSystem(
const char *SystemName, // In
int     LinkType,
void     *Arg,
const char *UserName,
const char *Password
);
```

First parameter id definitively a "pointer to char", you *should* declare it like that:

```
lib.CAENHVInitSystem.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int, c_int, c_char_p, c_char_p, c_char_p]
```

In addition:

```
ret_init =  lib.CAENHVInitSystem(0, 0, address, userName, passwd)
#                                ^
```

You pass *NULL* as `SystemName` (as NULL is `((void*)0)` on most systems). According to [the doc](https://totem-dcs.web.cern.ch/totem-dcs/index.php?dir=E.03.01&file=15.TechnicalInformationManual.pdf) I quickly read, this is not explicitly supported.

> This is the first function with parameter `SystemName` to call, and it must be called for all the HV power supplies the user wants to control

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't make any difference. I also tried the function CAENHV_InitSystem wchich requires an integer as first argument and the result is the same. When I try to use an invalid linktype (like a string or c_int>5) I get the right result: linktype not supported.

Comment: @leonardo You have tried to pass a _valid_ string as first parameter ?

Comment: The second function still has problems, but I will try to sort it out. Thanks a lot.